# Match Names and IDs. Search for and Display Duplicate Values (Name + ID) Using a Form in MS Access 2016

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm working with a database table that has a list of Names and the corresponding IDs. I created a form on MS Access 2016 where I enter a name and it displays the name and its corresponding ID (just display, I'm not updating or editing the table values). However, the table contains duplicate names. So when I enter a name (e.g. John Smith), I want it to return all John Smiths and their unique IDs. But right now my code only returns the first John Smith.

My current code is this:

```
Private Sub Command79_Click()
    NameTxt.SetFocus
    NameTxt.Text = NameTxt.Text & vbNewLine & Entry.Value

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strsql As String
    strsql = "SELECT ID, FullName, SSID FROM AllData WHERE FullName Like '*" & Entry.Value & "'"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)
    
    SSIDTxt.SetFocus
    
    If rst.EOF Then
        SSIDTxt.Text = SSIDTxt.Text & vbNewLine & "Error: Name Doesn't Have a Match."
    Else
        SSIDTxt.Text = SSIDTxt.Text & vbNewLine & rst.Fields("SSID")
    End If
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    
    Entry.SetFocus
    Entry.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Basically, after I write a name in NameTxt and click on the search button (Command79), if the name matches a record in the table AllData, then it displays the ID in SSIDTxt.

I also attached an image of my form after searching for a duplicate name and receiving a single result instead of two results.

[image: form view]

Comment: Would have to loop through recordset and concatenate data as a delimited string. Why not set the RowSource of a combobox to the SQL instead? This is called a cascading or conditional combobox (or listbox). Set textbox Value instead of Text and textbox does not need to have focus.

Comment: Actually, why not have a combobox for selection of student to begin with?

Comment: Could it be that one of your John Smiths has two spaces between first and last name? I would also suggest changing your SQL slightly to include a trailing asterisk: `Like '*" & Entry.Value & "*'"`

Comment: If it is an issue with spaces you could also get every record with John Smith regardless of any extra spaces by using `WHERE Replace(FullName,' ','') Like '*" & Replace(Entry.Value,' ','') & "*'"`

Comment: You take only 1 (first) record from recordset. While do not ``while not rst.EOF :  
  SSIDTxt.value = SSIDTxt.value & vbNewLine & rst.Fields("SSID") : rst.movenext`` ?

Comment: @ValNik your line of code worked and now I can display duplicate values. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

since I've got the answer, I thought I should post the code and the results.

'''

```
If Entry.Value <> "" Then

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strsql As String
    strsql = "SELECT ID, FullName, SSID FROM AllData WHERE FullName Like '*" & Entry.Value & "'"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)

    If rst.EOF Then
        NameTxt.SetFocus
        If NameTxt.Text = "" Then
            NameTxt.Text = Entry.Value
            SSIDTxt.SetFocus
            SSIDTxt.Text = "Error: Name Doesn't Have a Match."
        Else
            NameTxt.Text = NameTxt.Text & vbNewLine & Entry.Value
            SSIDTxt.SetFocus
            SSIDTxt.Text = SSIDTxt.Text & vbNewLine & "Error: Name Doesn't Have a Match."
        End If
    End If

    While Not rst.EOF
        NameTxt.SetFocus
        If NameTxt.Text = "" Then
            NameTxt.Text = Entry.Value
            SSIDTxt.SetFocus
            SSIDTxt.Text = rst.Fields("SSID")
        Else
            NameTxt.Text = NameTxt.Text & vbNewLine & Entry.Value
            SSIDTxt.SetFocus
            SSIDTxt.Text = SSIDTxt.Text & vbNewLine & rst.Fields("SSID")
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

    Entry.SetFocus
    Entry.Value = ""

End If
```

'''

[the image shows both single and duplicate names, proving that the code works for displaying duplicates and non-duplicates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpMe7.png)

Comment: @June7 comment above ``Set textbox Value instead of Text and textbox does not need to have focus``. This is default use case for ``TextBox``.